# spring batch with spring data JPA using RepositoryItemReader and Repository Item writer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

spring batch with spring data JPA using RepositoryItemReader and Repository Item writer.

I dont see any example implementation online , please throw some light or examples ..code links

Answer (score 0):

```
RepositoryItemReader<MemberDemographics> repositoryReport = new 
RepositoryItemReader<MemberDemographics>();

repositoryReport.setRepository(memberDemoGraphicsRepository); //Repository class refferance 

repositoryReport.setMethodName("getMemberDemoGraphicByGroupID");//repository method
List<Long> groupIDs = groupDemogrRepository.getValidGroups();
for (Long id : groupIDs) {
    List<Long> parameters = new ArrayList<>()   ;
    parameters.add(id);
    setAgrguments(parameters);
}
    
repositoryReport.setArguments(getAgrguments());// Mehtod Arguments
```

Comment: can i know how to use RepositoryItemWriter ,